# Redirecting .html internally on Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm wanting to redirect all requests for .html pages to a perl script for processing. However, for some reason I'm also being redirected for pages with no .html like the root site / as well as directories like /images/

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(html)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /page.cgi [L]
```

How can I make it so it will only redirect requests ending in .html

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests with no specified file default to requesting index.html in a particular directory, per a different Apache config option. Maybe try putting a blank index.php file in those directories (assuming your server also runs php?). You'd have to add index.php in httpd.conf as a recognized index file. That way, requests for a directory with no file specified would default to index.php, which does not trigger your re-write rule because it's not a .html.

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't think of that little thing, just setting DirectoryIndex do never do index.html fixed the problem. Thanks!